# Android - How can I convert big number to string from jsonobject using java?

Tags: java, android, json, type-conversion

I have a response from the web service and this response is a json type string. I get the STHAR_GCMIK value here using obj.getString().

This code works correctly up to 6 digit values, but it returns 4.0E+7 for the value 4000000. I tried different solutions but failed. How can I display the value here as it is?

```
private AttrsSiparis parseSiparisBilgisi(String data) {
        AttrsSiparis siparisBilgileri = new AttrsSiparis();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Irsaliye Result Parse : STHAR_GCMIK " + obj.getString("STHAR_GCMIK"));

                //siparisBilgileri.miktarlar.add(obj.getString("STHAR_GCMIK"));
                siparisBilgileri.miktarlar.add(new BigDecimal(obj.getString("STHAR_GCMIK")).toString());
                
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return siparisBilgileri;
    }
```

Comment: If you only run `obj.getString("STHAR_GCMIK")` is it properly shown? Or, in other words, is the display error originating after the conversion to `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I only run `obj.getString("STHAR_GCMIK")` , it converts 4000000 to 4.0E+7 and add to list. I think getString() doing this.

Comment: If you run `obj.getObject("STHAR_GCMIK")` or `obj.getLong("STHAR_GCMIK")` and do so via a debugger, what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format it to `double` via `.getDouble("STHAR_GCMTK")` and then convert that to `String`.

Comment: I resolved with double parse and then formatting as you said : 

`siparisBilgileri.miktarlar.add(String.format("%.0f",Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("STHAR_GCMIK"))));`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I display the value here as it is?

I guess you are talking about displaying the already parsed `BigDecimal`. If so, then if you are logging or printing it, it uses its [`toString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal#toString()) method. This method uses the scientific notation by default.

If you want to display the number *as it is* You have to use the [`toPlainString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal#toPlainString()) method - it doesn't use the scientific notation.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I solved this error by first converting the incoming data to double type and then formatting it as string type.
`siparisBilgileri.miktarlar.add(String.format("%.0f",Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("STHAR_GCMIK"))));`